# Middlware code is not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use this code which need to create folder if it doesn't exist
and it's not working, while debug and put BP on `fs.mkdir` It doesn't get into it, any idea what could be the problem ?

```
...
app.use(makeDir) 
...
function makeDir(folder) {

  destinationFolder = folder;
  return (req, res, next) => {

      fs.mkdir(folder, (err) => {
        if (!!err && err.code !== 'EEXIST') {
            logger.info(`Error ' ${err}`);
        }
        next();
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Not enough information, what is `app` ? And the sequence in which you mount your middlewares matter

Comment: The callback that is called is `makeDir`, not the lambda you are returning from it.

Comment: `app.use(makeDir())` invoke the makeDir function to return the lambda as highlighted by Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `app.use(makeDir)` while you should be calling:

`app.use(makeDir('/some/folder'))`

The `makeDir` function is not a middleware function itself but is returning the middleware function

Answer (score 0):

Did you try defining the function `makeDir` before `app.use(makeDir)`. Also make sure that `app.use(makeDir)` is before your route definitions.

Comment: This is not really the case. TommyBs's comment is on the right track here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304589/middlware-code-is-not-called#comment89585915_51304589